# In p-adic metric, what is the distance between 0.9999... and 1?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

In 10-adic (though 10 is not a prime number) metric, we know that

> $\Vert1-0.9999...\Vert=\Vert\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{10^n}\Vert=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}10^n\rightarrow\infty$.

However, from another point of view: $0.9999...=3\times\frac{1}{3}=1 $, we then should have

> $\Vert1-0.9999...\Vert=\Vert1-1\Vert=\Vert0\Vert=0$

Which one should be right? Or, in 10-adic system, we should have

> $0=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}10^n\rightarrow\infty$

or say, $0$ is infinitely close to $\infty$ in the 10-adic system?

Comment: I'm not sure you could say $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}10^n=\infty$ in the $10$-adic system

Comment: @J.W.Tanner so at least, $0=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}10^n$ is right?

Comment: What $10$- adic number do you mean by writing "0.99999..."?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg "0.99999..." is not a 10- adic number, instead it is a rational number. I just use the 10-adic metric, which is the a metric on rational number. This metric finally gives the 10-adic number. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#cite_note-zerodiv-8, 'every positive rational number $r$ can be uniquely expressed as $r =: \frac{a}{b} 10^d$... and the  the 10-adic "absolute value" of $r$ be
$|r|_{10}:=|10^{d}|_{10}=\frac {1}{10^{d}}$'

Comment: Well then that rational number is $1$, just written in an unconventional way, and that makes your question pointless, as $1-0.9999....=0$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Not yet. There are two point of views. My second point of view is exactly same as what you talking about. However, please check the first point of view.

Answer (score 2):

The error in your first line is that you are not precise enough about what limits are taken with respect to which metric. If the expression $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{10^n}$ is supposed to mean the limit with respect to $10$-adic value, then the first equality in that line is wrong; if it is supposed to mean the limit with respect to the usual Euclidean metric, then the second equality in that line is wrong.

The first equality i.e.

> $\Vert1-0.9999...\Vert=\Vert\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{10^n}\Vert$

is true *if the limit is understood to be with respect to usual (Euclidean) metric on $\mathbb Q$* just because both sides, and actually *the expressions that sit inside the $\Vert \cdot \Vert$*, are both $0$. (It is *not* true if the limit is meant w.r.t the $10$-adic topology, i.e. if that's what the limit is supposed to mean, your first mistake is already here.) Of course we would also have, and could write the same insight as,

> $\Vert 0\Vert=\Vert\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\Vert$

or

> $\Vert0\Vert=\Vert\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(-1^n)\frac{\lfloor 3\sin(n)\rfloor}{7n}\Vert$

etc.

But then the following equality

> $\Vert\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{10^n}\Vert\stackrel{?}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}10^n$

is **wrong**, because even though it is true (for $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ meaning the $10$-adic value) that $\Vert \frac{1}{10^n}\Vert=10^n$ for each $n$, the map

$$x \mapsto \Vert x \Vert$$

is **not continuous at $0$** when viewed as a map $(\mathbb Q, \text{Euclidean metric}) \rightarrow (\mathbb Q, \text{Euclidean metric})$, as your example, or mine above, all show. So you cannot just pull the limits out of that function.

(As an aside, in another answer I [recently pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3608893/96384) that that map would also not be continuous at $0$ when viewed as a map $(\mathbb Q, p\text{-adic metric}) \rightarrow (\mathbb Q, p\text{-adic metric})$. It *would be continuous*, by definition, when viewed as a map

$$(\mathbb Q, p\text{-adic metric}) \rightarrow (\mathbb Q, \text{Euclidean metric}).$$

But if you want to use that to make your second equality true, then, as said, you have to interpret the limit sitting inside the value signs in $\Vert\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{10^n}\Vert$ as a $10$-adic one, and then the first equality is wrong as pointed out at the beginning.)

Comment: Thank you. **Discontinuity** explains everything. But I still think $\Vert\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{10^n}\Vert$ is an infinity value and can be denoted as  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}10^n$. However,  **$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}10^n$ is definitely *NOT* the $0$!** The metric is like the discontinuous function $y=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1/x, & x\neq0\\
0, & x=0
\end{array}\right.$. Though $x\rightarrow0$ we get the infinity value $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{x}$, this does NOT mean $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{x}=0$. Am I right?

Comment: Again: What is the $L:= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{10^n}$ supposed to mean? Limit with respect to the Euclidean metric? Then we have $L=0$, and hence its value is $\Vert L \Vert=0$. If, on the other hand, $L$ is defined via the $10$-adic metric, then it does not exist.

Comment: $L:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{10^n}$ is in Euclidean metric, it is same as the $x$ of $x\rightarrow0$. And $L=0$ is at the sense of limit or approach way. When $x\rightarrow0$, we may say $x=0$ in the approach sense, however this does not mean $y(x\rightarrow0)=y(0)$. More clearly, in the discontinuous function $y=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1/x, & x\neq0\\
0, & x=0
\end{array}\right.$, if I ask $x=L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{10^n}$, we should have $y(x)=1/x=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}10^n$ instead of $y(x\rightarrow0)=y(0)=0$, because it's a **discontinuous** function at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The following series diverges with respect to the 10-adic absolute value (not measure) because of the first argument you give. $$0.9999... = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 9 *10^{-n}$$

This is not a representation of $1$ in the 10-adics just like

$$\frac{-1}{9} = ...1111 =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty 10^n$$

is not a representation of $-1/9$ in the reals, but is perfectly fine in the context of 10-adics. A simple way to think of it is if a p-adic number has infinitely many digits to the right, it doesn't converge to represent a p-adic number just like a real number with infinitely many digits to the left doesn't converge to represent a real number.

Comment: This is true. However, I think here I just give an $p$-adic absolute value of a ***real number*** $0.9999...$  ($p$-adic absolute value seems is defined for ***real numbers*** instead of ***$p$-adic numbers***?). And from the fact that the two ***real numbers*** $0.999...$ and $1$ are same, I show that the two $p$-adic absolute values $0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}10^n$ are same.

Comment: The p-adic absolute value is defined on rational numbers, not real numbers. One way to think of constructing the p-adics or real numbers is to think of them as the completion of the rational numbers with respect to these different absolute values.